# Repairing Foil Faced Insulation

Tags: insulation, basement-insulation

I removed some wood paneling which was glued to some foil lined insulation.  In the process of removing it, some of the foil facing tore off.

What’s the right material to replace this with? If it’s meant to be a vapor barrier I’d assume just foil HVAC tape is fine, but if it’s meant to be semi-permeable I have no idea.

The insulation is below grade, pressed against the concrete foundation.

[Image](https://imgur.com/gallery/7dXDA59)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the foil HVAC tape you mentioned.  If the insulation was faced with foil, it's probably not semi-permeable.  And even if it was, sealing off a small part of the insulation with an impermeable material will not affect the permeability of the wall as a whole.